# Escaping out of text field based search bar

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, keylistener

I have a menu bar with a search-bar that is implemented with a `JTextField` like this:

```
public class Ui_Frame {
    private static JFrame f;
    private static DrawPanel drawPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Ui_Frame::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        f = new JFrame("Frame");
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel(); //A class that extends JPanel where I draw

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu j_menu_data = new JMenu("Data");
        JTextField j_menu_searchfield = new JTextField();
        j_menu_searchfield.setSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        menubar.add(j_menu_data);
        menubar.add(j_menu_searchfield);
        f.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(drawPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

I have `KeyListener`s for the `DrawPanel` class, these work just fine. The problem is that when I add the search bar `JTextField` to the menu bar as above, everything I write is being written to the text field and my key listeners do not trigger. I cannot "get out" of the text field, so If I click inside the area where I am drawing all the keys I press are still put into the text field.

I have tried `getFocus()` for the `DrawPanel` but to no avail.

How to solve this?

**EDIT**:
DrawPanel class so you have all the classes you need to run it:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public DrawPanel() {
        addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener());
        this.setBackground(new Color(220,220,220));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2D);
    }

    class CustomKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                System.out.println("Pressed SPACE");
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `//A class that extends JPanel where I draw` Better to explain in code rather than a code comment. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: Key events are dispatched to the component with focus. By default a JPanel is not focusable so the key events are dispatched to the text field.

Comment: @camickr I know, but how do I solve that ? There must be a way to have a searchbar and a drawing panel and respond differently to the keys being pressed depending on which component is active, right?

Comment: That is what key bindings are for. You have posted a [mre] so we can't give a more specific answer.

Comment: okay ill have a look at the key bindings. I added the DrawPanel class

Comment: That is not an [mre]. We can't compile and test. There is no frame, not "search text field". So how does this demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Why can you not compile and test? If you copy the code above and put it in 2 classes you can run the thing. If you do, you see a window pop up consisting of a text input-field and a Jpanel. As the text input-field is active and I cannot "get out of it" the KeyListener for the JPanel does not fire, which is the problem described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch your *Swing* application, the `JTextField` initially has the keyboard focus. You know this because you see the cursor flashing inside the `JTextField`.

Clicking on the `DrawPanel` with the mouse does not transfer the keyboard focus to the `DrawPanel`. You know this because after clicking the mouse inside the `DrawPanel`, the cursor is still flashing inside the `JTextField`.

You can transfer the keyboard focus from the `JTextField` to the `DrawPanel` by hitting the TAB key on the keyboard since that is the default focus traversal key. You know that the `JTextField` no longer has keyboard focus because there is no flashing cursor in it.

If you really want the `DrawPanel` to gain keyboard focus by clicking the mouse in it, you can add a `MouseListener` to `DrawPanel`, as demonstrated in the below code which is essentially your code (for class `DrawPanel`) with a `MouseListener` added.

Note that I did not change class `Ui_Frame`.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    public DrawPanel() {
        addKeyListener(new CustomKeyListener());
        addMouseListener(this);
        this.setBackground(new Color(220,220,220));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2D);
    }

    class CustomKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                System.out.println("Pressed SPACE");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println(this.requestFocusInWindow());
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    }
}
```

Note that method `requestFocusInWindow()` returns `true` if it succeeds.